# windows store certification kit - c++ library validation issues

Tags: c++, windows-store-apps, app-certification-kit

I'm trying to port a c++ library to universal windows for a windows store app.
Using x86 developer command prompt in visual studio 2015 v14.0.24720.00 update 1 on Windows 10.

Wondering what I'm doing wrong - everything compiles and links fine with the following flags:

`cl /nologo /FoBuild\Obj\Windows\Release\[OBJ_FILE].obj /c /MD /Ox /W4 /EHsc /FRBuild\Obj\Windows\Release\ -DDEFINE_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DDEFINE_TRACE -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -DDEFINE_WINDOWS_UNIVERSAL /AI "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\store\references" /WX /ZW /D "WINAPI_FAMILY=2" -IBuild\Include [SOURCE].cpp`

and:

`link /nologo /opt:ref /map Ws2_32.lib /APPCONTAINER /dll  /out:Build\Obj\Windows\Release\myDll.dll [OBJ_FILE.obj]*`

Getting a whole bunch of unusual looking wack validation errors for things that surely should be standard functions such as malloc and std::bad_alloc etc.
And furthermore, a lot of these not supported APIs seem to actually exist in the whitelist files even though they are declared not supported.
Not sure what I'm doing wrong as it all compiles fine with the /ZW /EHsc /D "WINAPI_FAMILY=2" switches as documented here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh700130.aspx

The documentation on that page states explicity that any use of CRT functions that are not allowed in a Windows 8.x Store app will cause a compile-time error when you use the /ZW flag.  It all compiles fine, even on the arm toolchain.

Also puzzled as to why some of the refs are in vcruntime140 and some are in api-ms-win-crt-*.dll.

Can anyone shed any light on these issues please?

Full list of errors below.

Cheers

Iain

```
◦API _time64 in api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _cexit in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _crt_atexit in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _execute_onexit_table in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _initialize_narrow_environment in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _initialize_onexit_table in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _initterm in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _initterm_e in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _invalid_parameter_noinfo_noreturn in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _register_onexit_function in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _seh_filter_dll in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API abort in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API terminate in api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _strdup in api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API strncat in api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API strncmp in api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API strncpy in api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __acrt_iob_func in api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __stdio_common_vfprintf in api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __stdio_common_vsnprintf_s in api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __stdio_common_vsprintf in api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API fflush in api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _callnewh in api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API calloc in api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API free in api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API malloc in api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API rand in api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API srand in api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API ?InitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAJH@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API ?UninitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAXH@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _CxxThrowException in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __CxxFrameHandler3 in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __std_exception_copy in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __std_exception_destroy in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __std_terminate in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __std_type_info_destroy_list in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __telemetry_main_invoke_trigger in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __telemetry_main_return_trigger in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API __vcrt_InitializeCriticalSectionEx in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _except_handler4_common in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API _purecall in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API memcpy in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API memmove in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API memset in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API ?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ in msvcp140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API ?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z in msvcp140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API ?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z in msvcp140.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API CreateEventA in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API CreateEventW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API CreateSemaphoreA in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API GetModuleHandleW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API InitializeCriticalSection in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API SetUnhandledExceptionFilter in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API TerminateProcess in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API TlsAlloc in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API TlsFree in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API TlsGetValue in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API TlsSetValue in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API UnhandledExceptionFilter in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
◦API WaitForSingleObject in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. myDll.dll calls this API.
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that I needed to build against vs2013 toolchain for windows 8.1 library, not vs2015.  Don't forget to check the dependency on universal c++ runtime in your app dependencies as well or it will fail to load the dll.

use vcvars.bat in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC

Compiler:

cl /nologo /FoBuild\Obj\Windows\Release\MyObj.obj -c /MD /Ox /c /W4 /EHsc /FRBuild\Obj\Windows\Release\ -DDEFINE_LITTLE_ENDIAN -DDEFINE_TRACE -DDEFINE_WINDOWS_UNIVERSAL -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS /D "_WINDLL" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.1\ExtensionSDKs\Microsoft.VCLibs\12.0\References\CommonConfiguration\neutral\platform.winmd" /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd" /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\References\CommonConfiguration\Neutral\Windows.winmd" /WX /ZW /ZW:nostdlib /D "WINAPI_FAMILY=WINAPI_FAMILY_APP" /D "**WRL_NO_DEFAULT_LIB**" /Gy /Zc:inline /Zc:wchar_t /TP -IBuild\Include MySrc.cpp

Linker:

link /nologo /OPT:REF /map Ws2_32.lib kernel32.lib /APPCONTAINER  /DYNAMICBASE /NXCOMPAT /MACHINE:X86 /SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS /LIBPATH:"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\lib\store" /dll  /out:Build\Obj\Windows\Release\myDll.dll [Build\Obj\Windows\Release*.obj]

See also:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b4d0ca1a-6b35-49e2-9074-886cc36f80d4/uwpc-store-apps-compiling-c-library-on-command-line-causes-rejections?forum=wpdevelop

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2012/09/28/c-runtime-for-windows-8-store-apps/

Cheers
Iain