# UWP Windows-10 WACK tests Errors

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, windows-10-universal, c++-cx, wack

I am new to Windows app development. I have built a C# app targeting, Windows 10 desktop & mobile platforms. My C# app calls into Windows Runtime Component written in C++ (c++/cx).

I followed this [MSDN Link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/windows-app-certification-kit) to run WACK test.

I have **Windows App Certification Kit 10.0** installed on my machine. To run the test, I do **Validate Store App -> Select my app from list of installed apps on the machine**. My app is installed in release mode. When I run WACK test, **Supported API test** fails with following:

```
API ??0Delegate@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ??0Exception@Platform@@Q$AAA@H@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ??0NotImplementedException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ??0Object@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?AlignedFree@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAXPAX@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?Allocate@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAPAXII@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?AllocateException@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAPAXII@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?Free@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAXPAX@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?GetActivationFactory@Details@Platform@@YGJPAVModuleBase@1WRL@Microsoft@@PAUHSTRING__@@PAPAUIActivationFactory@@@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?GetActivationFactoryByPCWSTR@@YGJPAXAAVGuid@Platform@@PAPAX@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?GetIBoxArrayVtable@Details@Platform@@YGPAXPAX@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?GetIidsFn@@YGJHPAKPBU__s_GUID@@PAPAVGuid@Platform@@@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?InitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAJH@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?ReleaseTarget@ControlBlock@Details@Platform@@AAEXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?TerminateModule@Details@Platform@@YG_NPAVModuleBase@1WRL@Microsoft@@@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?UninitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAXH@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseAccessDeniedException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseCOMException@@YGXJ@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseChangedStateException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseClassNotRegisteredException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseDisconnectedException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseFailureException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseInvalidArgumentException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseInvalidCastException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseNotImplementedException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseNullReferenceException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseObjectDisposedException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOperationCanceledException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfBoundsException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfMemoryException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_WinRTraiseWrongThreadException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?__abi_translateCurrentException@@YGJ_N@Z in vccorlib140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API _CxxThrowException in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API __CxxFrameHandler3 in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API __std_exception_copy in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API __std_exception_destroy in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API __std_terminate in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API __std_type_info_destroy_list in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API __telemetry_main_invoke_trigger in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API __telemetry_main_return_trigger in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API __vcrt_InitializeCriticalSectionEx in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API _except_handler4_common in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API _purecall in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API memcpy in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API memmove in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API memset in vcruntime140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ in msvcp140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z in msvcp140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z in msvcp140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ??1_StructuredTaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ in concrt140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?Free@Concurrency@@YAXPAX@Z in concrt140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?_CheckTaskCollection@_UnrealizedChore@details@Concurrency@@IAEXXZ in concrt140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API ?_RunAndWait@_StructuredTaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@QAG?AW4_TaskCollectionStatus@23@PAV_UnrealizedChore@23@@Z in concrt140.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API GetModuleHandleW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API TlsAlloc in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API TlsFree in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API TlsGetValue in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API TlsSetValue in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
    
API UnhandledExceptionFilter in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. sample.dll calls this API.
```

On further googling, I found these [Link-1](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/wack-errors.295053/) and [Link-2](http://www.npruehs.de/windows-store-app-validation-fails/)

The possible solution in the above links is to uninstall  **KB 2976978** update & rerun WACK tests [MS Support Error Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3026757)

My machine doesnt seem to have this **KB 2976978** update though.

 **Control Panel\Programs\Programs and Features** ***View Installed Updates*** or ***Search Installed Updates*** doesnt seem to find the above update.

 I have checked this: [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37110586/windows-store-certification-kit-c-library-validation-issues) As mentioned in this SO post even in my case everything compiles fine with **/ZW /EHsc /D** flags

 My VS details are:

```
MS Visual Studio Professional 2015 

Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2 

MS .NET Framework 

Version 4.6.01038
```

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem was that, my C++ native lib was referencing Desktop CRT dll's(**vccorlib140.dll**) instead of store CRT dll(**vccorlib140_app.dll**).

The app was referencing Desktop CRT because, I was linking my app with libs from this location:

> **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib**

Turns out to build a store app we need to reference libs from this location:

> **C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\lib\store**